# Use .p12 to create CA?

Tags: authentication, ssl, ca

I have generate .p12 file from my server. But righ now we are developing IOS app which requires CA to implement it.

We are using Amazon EC load balancer server, so i have not idea where I can get CA, also is it possible that .p12 can generate CA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A CA is a Certificate Authority. It is an organization that generates a public/private key pair for you. A PKCS#12 is a standard that explains how to store public/private key pairs in a file. Your .p12 file is such a file. It is a keystore that contains digital certificates (a public and a private key pair) as defined in PKCS#12.

If you have a .p12, there are two options:

- Either your certificates are self-signed. In this case, you have created your own public and private key pair and you've stored it inside a .p12 file. As no CA is involved, there is no way to check if you created those certificates, or if somebody else *impersonating you* created those certificates.
- Or you obtained that .p12 file from a CA. In this case, the CA signed your certificate and there is a certificate chain that eventually leads to the *root certificate* of your CA. A CA doesn't hand out such certificate to just anybody. A CA will first check that you are who you say you are. This way, whichever party gets confronted with your certificate (for instance because you used your private key to sign your code), knows that you are who you say you are, provided that your CA is a trusted party (there are CAs and then there are CAs).

This image shows how it works:

[image]

You are Bob, Apple is Alice, Trent is your CA. Apple wants you to work with a CA because Apple doesn't know you, but Apple knows CA. Once you make yourself known to the CA and once the CA trusts you, Apple will trust you.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob to find out how the names in this image were chosen.

So the real question is: can you extract your public key from your .p12 file and show it to us so that we can see if your certificate is self-signed or if it's signed by a CA? Without that info, I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: yes! i finally understand it, thanks for great help. our SSL can process